# Importing excel data to datagrid using interop C#

Tags: c#, datagrid, import

I have just started on importing excel data to datagrid.I found a code and tried in on my system but I'm net getting anything in the datagrid.Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Also if anyone has a working code can u please share it with me.
Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;



namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList test = ProcessWorkbook("C:\\Users\\s_kamalaksha_prabhu\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx");
            if (test != null)
                dataGridView1.DataSource = test;

        }


        public ArrayList ProcessWorkbook(string filePath)
        {

            string file = filePath;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wkb = null;
            ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
            try
            {
                excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                wkb = ExcelTools.OpenBook(excel, file, false, true, false);

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = wkb.Sheets["Employees$"] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = null;

                if (sheet != null)
                    range = sheet.get_Range("A1:X6702", System.Type.Missing);


                if (range != null)
                {
                    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range r in range)
                    {
                        al.Add(r.Text);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //if you need to handle stuff
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (wkb != null)
                    ExcelTools.ReleaseRCM(wkb);

                if (excel != null)
                    ExcelTools.ReleaseRCM(excel);
            }
            return al;
        }

        //----------------
        public static class ExcelTools
        {
            public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook OpenBook(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelInstance, string fileName, bool readOnly, bool editable,
            bool updateLinks)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook book = excelInstance.Workbooks.Open(
                    fileName, updateLinks, readOnly,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, editable, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                return book;
            }

            public static void ReleaseRCM(object o)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    o = null;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the excel sheet actually opening?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this is supposed to do:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range r in range)
{
    al.Add(r.Text);
}
```

If you want to go through the cells use range.Cells. For rows use range.Rows
I guess if you want to fill a grid you'll want to do something like:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row in range.Rows)
{
    // Add a new row
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell in row.Cells)
    {
       // Write to the cells' column on the current row
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied the code from net. I was assigned a task but I have no idea what interop is. If possible can someone please shar a working code that will take employee names and ids from excel sheet and display in datagrid.It will be a huge favour.